# How fix the woocommerce issue with Theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to use woocommerce and I installed the woocommerce on the new wordpress installed website, woocommerce was working fine, then I installed a theme and woocommerce shop page looks like this :

[image]

I tried to remove this piece of code from theme function.php file :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
//add_shortcode( 'sh_animate_it', '_sh_animate_it' );
function _sh_animate_it( $atts, $contents = null )
{
    return include( 'includes/modules/shortcodes/animate_it.php' );
}
```

Now it's a little better, the page looks like this :

[image]

But it's not showing as default how woocommce shop page looks like. It's not showing image or anything.

Second thing , Products are showing in very strange way :

[image]

No add to cart button , No checkout etc , But in backend there are all the pages like the checkout page , cart page etc

So what is the issue with this theme and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

It Conflicts on the woocommerce plugin folder and the theme woocommerce folder. You delete the woocomerce folder in the theme folder.